# UnsatisfiedLinkError & no such method (jogl, gluegen, jogamp)

Tags: buffer, processing, jogl, slice, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I wrote a program using Processing(which uses jogl and gluegen), and am using PApplet to run it in a java application in NetBeans.

I am unable to run my program (by running the jar) outside the IDE - neither on my local windows 64-bit machine using command line, nor on a external linux server (which is where I would like to run the program) using X11 forwarding

I previously was able to run the program via command line on my windows machine, but ran into trouble after testing on the linux server.    I think there may have been some issues with paths or something after I downloaded the linux versions of the same jars

This is the error I receive from the linux machine:

```
Exception in thread "Animation Thread" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: jogamp.common.jvm.JVMUtil.initialize(Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;)Z 
        at jogamp.common.jvm.JVMUtil.initialize(Native Method) 
        at jogamp.common.jvm.JVMUtil.<clinit>(JVMUtil.java:58) 
        at com.jogamp.common.os.Platform$1.run(Platform.java:212) 
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) 
        at com.jogamp.common.os.Platform.<clinit>(Platform.java:179) 
        at javax.media.opengl.GLProfile.<clinit>(GLProfile.java:82) 
        at processing.opengl.PJOGL.initSurface(PJOGL.java:250) 
        at processing.opengl.PGraphicsOpenGL.initPrimary(PGraphicsOpenGL.java:6310) 
        at processing.opengl.PGraphicsOpenGL.requestDraw(PGraphicsOpenGL.java:1653) 
        at processing.core.PApplet.run(PApplet.java:2256) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

this is the error I get from trying to run the jar on my machine using command line:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.jogamp.common.nio.Buffers.slice2Float(Ljava/nio 
/Buffer;[FII)Ljava/nio/FloatBuffer; 
        at jogamp.opengl.ProjectFloat.<init>(ProjectFloat.java:181) 
        at jogamp.opengl.ProjectFloat.<init>(ProjectFloat.java:167) 
        at jogamp.opengl.ProjectFloat.<init>(ProjectFloat.java:163) 
        at javax.media.opengl.glu.GLU.<init>(GLU.java:164) 
        at processing.opengl.PJOGL.<init>(PJOGL.java:218) 
        at processing.opengl.PGraphicsOpenGL.createPGL(PGraphicsOpenGL.java:1744 
) 
        at processing.opengl.PGraphicsOpenGL.<init>(PGraphicsOpenGL.java:518) 
        at processing.opengl.PGraphics3D.<init>(PGraphics3D.java:37) 
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) 

        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) 

        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Sou 
rce) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source) 
        at processing.core.PApplet.makeGraphics(PApplet.java:1919) 
        at processing.core.PApplet.size(PApplet.java:1771) 
        at processing.core.PApplet.size(PApplet.java:1742) 
        at noblis.farag.MySketch.setup(MySketch.java:132) 
        at processing.core.PApplet.handleDraw(PApplet.java:2361) 
        at processing.core.PGraphicsJava2D.requestDraw(PGraphicsJava2D.java:240) 

        at processing.core.PApplet.run(PApplet.java:2256) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) 
Exception in thread "Animation Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: com.jogamp.co 
mmon.nio.Buffers.slice2Float(Ljava/nio/Buffer;[FII)Ljava/nio/FloatBuffer; 
        at processing.core.PApplet.makeGraphics(PApplet.java:1944) 
        at processing.core.PApplet.size(PApplet.java:1771) 
        at processing.core.PApplet.size(PApplet.java:1742) 
        at noblis.farag.MySketch.setup(MySketch.java:132) 
        at processing.core.PApplet.handleDraw(PApplet.java:2361) 
        at processing.core.PGraphicsJava2D.requestDraw(PGraphicsJava2D.java:240) 

        at processing.core.PApplet.run(PApplet.java:2256) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Any idea about why I can run it in the IDE but not outside? or any way to package it so that it can run outside the IDE?

thanks

Comment: Fixed: http://forum.jogamp.org/UnsatisfiedLinkError-tp4032562p4032576.html